# Common object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, singleton

I am trying to use a global object in TypeScript. For example, when a remote call is done, the user details gets populated. I would like it to be available throughout the application and be bindable. Can someone point to an example how it can be done?

I am implementing this type of singleton class for the user details class.

User Details:

```
export class UserDetails {
//Gets populated for all the remote calls
userGuid: string;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
fullName: string;
isAuthenticated: boolean;

private static  _instance: UserDetails = new UserDetails();
constructor() {
    if (UserDetails._instance) {
        throw new Error("Error: Instantiation failed: Use UserDetails.User instead of new.");
    }
    UserDetails._instance = this;
}

public static get User(): UserDetails {
    return UserDetails._instance;
}

@computedFrom('fullName')
get FullName(): string {
    return this.fullName;
}
```

}

Other Page:

```
import {UserDetails} from 'models/userDetails';
export class Home {
    /*@bindable*/router: Router;
    //This does not have the values 
    //that gets populated after every remote call to the server
    userDetails = UserDetails.User; 
}
```

Thanks in advance
Senthil S

Comment: Have a look here: http://blog.eexit.net/js-singleton-as-module/

Comment: @Amid - I thought that is what I am doing in my type script class. The example is in java script, so when I do the same in type script, it does not work as I wanted. Am I missing something?

Comment: No exactly. See my post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, have a look here: [singleton](http://blog.eexit.net/js-singleton-as-module/).

Then regarding your code, do the following changes:

1. Remove all attempts to implement singleton from UserDetails class ( `_instance` static field and so on)
2. In the end of the UserDetails.ts export singleton instance like this:

`export const DefaultUser = new UserDetails();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amid. Excellent. I started using static variables which also works for my case but I like this way to be consistent with the type script modules.